# "I was born in 1961" is ‘born’ past participle or an adjective here?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, parts-of-speech, past-participles

1. I was born in 1961.
   Some dictionaries like *Oxford Advanced dictionary*, *Collins* and most other lexicographers say that *born* is the past participle form of the verb *bear* and they say that the sentence is in the passive voice.
2. Some other dictionaries like *Cambridge Advanced* and some other dictionaries say that the sentence *I was born in 1961* is not in the passive voice since *born* is not the past participle of verb *bear* but it is an adjective here. Even grammarians seem to be divided on this matter.
   I hope this is the right platform to clarify my confusion

> [Tendulkar is gone](https://www.smh.com.au/sport/cricket/crickets-little-master-sachin-tendulkar-is-gone-the-mourning-begins-20131116-2xnu5.html).

Here *gone* is an adjective.
Similarly, in “I was born in 1961” the word *born* seems to be an adjective. Most grammarians I know consider it an adjective rather than a past participle. But it appears that both lexicographers and grammarians are divided on this grammatical issue.

I think it needs much more exhaustive explanation than the one provided in the older question.

Comment: Links to the dictionaries that claim "born" is an adjective would earn my upvote.

Comment: ,https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/born

Comment: The link should go in the question.

Comment: Also related (but on ELL) [The ambiguous "he is buried"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/107449/the-ambiguous-he-is-buried)

Comment: @Mari-LouA We shouldn't be encouraging people to use dictionaries for part of speech or other grammatical information. It's not what they're designed for! (And thus, they're very bad at it).

Comment: @Araucaria-  When an asker bases their question on what they read in a dictionary, they should name and include a link to that source. Then you or anyone else can post an answer explaining why the parts of speech in dictionaries need to be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an adjective.

"Born" (in the childbirth sense) is the past participle of "bear", and is restricted to the passive. It only occurs in short passives. So we can have [1] but not [2]:

> [1] *I was born in 1961*.
>
> [2] **I was born by a Greek peasant.*

Comment: What would be the correct version of [2]? _I was given birth by_...?

Comment: All the above comments or answers are rather confusing. It seems that my confusion is confounded.

Comment: @Jvlnarasimharao Why? It's clear that "born" (in the childbirth sense) is the past participle of "bear", and is found in such passive examples as the ones above.

Comment: But not in English.

Comment: @fev [2] could be _I was born **to** a Greek peasant_ but that still doesn't necessarily add an actual agent to the sentence.

Comment: It's one of the few English deponent verbs. Latin had lots of them, including 'speak' _loquor, loquari, locutus sum_, but I can't think of another English one. There are defective English verbs like modals and _beware_ and like that, but deponency in English is not between active and passive forms, but between past participles and predicate adjectives

Comment: We don't have 'deponent verbs' in English. It's as simple as that.

Comment: In meaning it's a regular passive not a deponent, which has passive form but active sense, cf the standard passive "I was made" which is the same as "I was born".